# 2 Approaches on Google Maps not working

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview, mapfragment

I have tried two approaches to implement Google maps on android and both are not working.

1st Approach - I implemented maps using fragments (**com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment**). In this approach I get an error and the it asks me to **UPDATE GOOGLE PLAY** store.

2nd approach - I implemented maps using MapView (**com.google.android.maps.MapView**). I get a server 3 error in this approach and display shows me a **blank grid**.

I even generated a new api key, but it was of no use.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have tested it on both - device and emulator

Comment: It was updated with latest version.

Answer (score 0):

you can use map v2 with :

```
        <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

with extends FragmentActivity

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

I went to the

```
Settings -> Software updates -> Check now
```

in Phone downloaded and installed some updates.
This time when i clicked on

```
Get Google Play Services (In the application )
```

Market automatically got updated to Google Play.

Map is getting displayed properly.

Comment: I tried this also and getting the same Update error. I could not find the software updates in settings.

Comment: Here are the logs:

`
09-02 06:39:01.339: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1053): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 3225100 but found 3136130  

09-02 06:39:01.619: D/dalvikvm(1053): GC_CONCURRENT freed 248K, 14% free 2522K/2912K, paused 13ms+26ms, total 153ms  

09-02 06:39:01.719: D/gralloc_goldfish(1053): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.  

09-02 06:39:15.439: I/jdwp(1053): Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping`

Comment: Blank map most of the times is problem with the API key, try to follow the given link here in the answer